# What is the best convention to define endpoints in Rest APIs?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, naming-conventions

I read an article on the internet which says to avoid rest end points naming with actions that we are trying to deal with ,rather than mentioning the actions use plural form of the entity that we are dealing with for an example if we are using with users then name the end points like api/users so this is really okay for a scenario which  have less end points which means having always different http request types.For an example if we consider the API there is only one type of @Get mapping , other types also same so in a scenario of having multiple end points with the same http request method what is the best way to name those end points?

Answer (score 1):

There's are very subtle different between what is RESTful services and what are webservices. From the spring official docs :

- Pretty URLs like /employees/3 aren’t REST.
- Merely using GET, POST, etc. aren’t REST.
- Having all the CRUD operations laid out aren’t REST.
  The web services which you've referred are known as RPC(Remote Procedure Call)

To get what a flavor of RESTful , Use Spring HATEOS a Spring project aimed at helping you write hypermedia-driven outputs. This tiny library/dependency will give us the constructs to define a RESTful service and then render it in an acceptible format for client consumption. You may more read [about Spring HATEOS here](https://spring.io/projects/spring-hateoas)

A critical ingredient to any RESTful service is adding links to relevant operations.

Now over to your Question,The REST end points which we get as feature in spring DATA REST and are HATEOS compliance (for CRUD operations) :

1. GET mapping at http://localhost:8080/users/ to list all entities.
2. GET mapping at http://localhost:8080/users/<existing_user_id> to list a single entity
3. POST mapping at http://localhost:8080/users/ along with body of JSON/XML to create a
   new entity.
4. PUT mapping at http://localhost:8080/users/<existing_user_id> to update a particular
   id  with updated content in body.
5. DELETE mapping at http://localhost:8080/users/<existing_user_id> to delete an entity.

   As you have observed by just seeing the url no one can guess what actions will take,
   it all depends on HTTP method type.
   If you want to read more about REST and HATEOS ( which provide a lot more features
   than CRUD such as pagiantion, sorting etc.)

Refer to these official Spring documentation on [HATEOS](https://spring.io/projects/spring-hateoas) and [RESTful services](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/)

Answer (score 0):

The only naming conventions that is generally followed in naming the APIs is to avoid verbs.

eg. if you want to upsert(insert/update) a user, POST /api/user will be good.
Getting a user -> GET /api/user/{id}
Getting all users -> GET /api/users

If you have any specific requirements, as such, you can mention here.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this article about Richardson Maturity Model : https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html

It contains all information to make well designed RESTful API